# Windows Forms Application error

Tags: c++, visual-c++

i am pretty new to c++ and i am writing a hypothecary credit calculator! Here is my Code :

PS: dont wonder i am german so there may be some german words but i dont think so !

```
#pragma once

namespace HypothekenRechner {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;

    /// <summary>
    /// Summary for Form1
    /// </summary>
    public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    int Year [100];
    int Mone[100];
    int Interes[100];
    int Redemptio[100];
    int c;
    int Money;
    int Percent;
    int Interest;
    int tp;
    int Redemption;

    public:

    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox5;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox6;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox7;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox8;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label6;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label7;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label8;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label9;
    public: 

        Form1(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //
            //TODO: Add the constructor code here
            //
        }

    protected:
        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        ~Form1()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox1;
    protected: 
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox2;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox3;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox4;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label2;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label3;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label4;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label5;

    private:
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        void InitializeComponent(void)
        {
            System::ComponentModel::ComponentResourceManager^  resources = (gcnew System::ComponentModel::ComponentResourceManager(Form1::typeid));
            this->textBox1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->textBox2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->textBox3 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->textBox4 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->label1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->label2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->label3 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->label4 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->label5 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->button1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->textBox5 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->textBox6 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->textBox7 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->textBox8 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->label6 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->label7 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->label8 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->label9 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // textBox1
            // 
            this->textBox1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(158, 12);
            this->textBox1->Name = L"textBox1";
            this->textBox1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 20);
            this->textBox1->TabIndex = 0;
            // 
            // textBox2
            // 
            this->textBox2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(158, 38);
            this->textBox2->Name = L"textBox2";
            this->textBox2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 20);
            this->textBox2->TabIndex = 1;
            // 
            // textBox3
            // 
            this->textBox3->Location = System::Drawing::Point(158, 64);
            this->textBox3->Name = L"textBox3";
            this->textBox3->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 20);
            this->textBox3->TabIndex = 2;
            // 
            // textBox4
            // 
            this->textBox4->Location = System::Drawing::Point(158, 90);
            this->textBox4->Name = L"textBox4";
            this->textBox4->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 20);
            this->textBox4->TabIndex = 3;
            // 
            // label1
            // 
            this->label1->AutoSize = true;
            this->label1->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::Transparent;
            this->label1->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Microsoft Sans Serif", 11.25F, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Bold, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point, 
                static_cast<System::Byte>(0)));
            this->label1->ForeColor = System::Drawing::Color::Black;
            this->label1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(1, 14);
            this->label1->Name = L"label1";
            this->label1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(79, 18);
            this->label1->TabIndex = 4;
            this->label1->Text = L"Hypothek";
            // 
            // label2
            // 
            this->label2->AutoSize = true;
            this->label2->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::Transparent;
            this->label2->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Microsoft Sans Serif", 11.25F, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Bold, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point, 
                static_cast<System::Byte>(0)));
            this->label2->ForeColor = System::Drawing::Color::Black;
            this->label2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(1, 40);
            this->label2->Name = L"label2";
            this->label2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(72, 18);
            this->label2->TabIndex = 5;
            this->label2->Text = L"Zinssatz";
            // 
            // label3
            // 
            this->label3->AutoSize = true;
            this->label3->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::Transparent;
            this->label3->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Microsoft Sans Serif", 11.25F, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Bold, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point, 
                static_cast<System::Byte>(0)));
            this->label3->ForeColor = System::Drawing::Color::Black;
            this->label3->Location = System::Drawing::Point(1, 66);
            this->label3->Name = L"label3";
            this->label3->Size = System::Drawing::Size(140, 18);
            this->label3->TabIndex = 6;
            this->label3->Text = L"Jährliche Zahlung";
            // 
            // label4
            // 
            this->label4->AutoSize = true;
            this->label4->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::Transparent;
            this->label4->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Microsoft Sans Serif", 11.25F, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Bold, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point, 
                static_cast<System::Byte>(0)));
            this->label4->ForeColor = System::Drawing::Color::Black;
            this->label4->Location = System::Drawing::Point(1, 92);
            this->label4->Name = L"label4";
            this->label4->Size = System::Drawing::Size(62, 18);
            this->label4->TabIndex = 7;
            this->label4->Text = L"Tilgung";
            // 
            // label5
            // 
            this->label5->AutoSize = true;
            this->label5->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::Transparent;
            this->label5->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Segoe Script", 24, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Bold, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point, 
                static_cast<System::Byte>(0)));
            this->label5->ForeColor = System::Drawing::Color::Black;
            this->label5->Location = System::Drawing::Point(12, 238);
            this->label5->Name = L"label5";
            this->label5->Size = System::Drawing::Size(256, 53);
            this->label5->TabIndex = 8;
            this->label5->Text = L"Tobias Rohde";
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this->button1->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Microsoft Sans Serif", 14.25F, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Regular, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point, 
                static_cast<System::Byte>(0)));
            this->button1->ForeColor = System::Drawing::SystemColors::ControlText;
            this->button1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(338, 248);
            this->button1->Name = L"button1";
            this->button1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(150, 40);
            this->button1->TabIndex = 9;
            this->button1->Text = L"Berechnen";
            this->button1->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this->button1->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::button1_Click);
            // 
            // textBox5
            // 
            this->textBox5->Location = System::Drawing::Point(388, 12);
            this->textBox5->Name = L"textBox5";
            this->textBox5->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 20);
            this->textBox5->TabIndex = 10;
            // 
            // textBox6
            // 
            this->textBox6->Location = System::Drawing::Point(388, 41);
            this->textBox6->Name = L"textBox6";
            this->textBox6->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 20);
            this->textBox6->TabIndex = 11;
            // 
            // textBox7
            // 
            this->textBox7->Location = System::Drawing::Point(388, 67);
            this->textBox7->Name = L"textBox7";
            this->textBox7->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 20);
            this->textBox7->TabIndex = 12;
            // 
            // textBox8
            // 
            this->textBox8->Location = System::Drawing::Point(388, 92);
            this->textBox8->Name = L"textBox8";
            this->textBox8->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 20);
            this->textBox8->TabIndex = 13;
            // 
            // label6
            // 
            this->label6->AutoSize = true;
            this->label6->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::Transparent;
            this->label6->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Microsoft Sans Serif", 11.25F, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Bold, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point, 
                static_cast<System::Byte>(0)));
            this->label6->ForeColor = System::Drawing::Color::Black;
            this->label6->Location = System::Drawing::Point(282, 14);
            this->label6->Name = L"label6";
            this->label6->Size = System::Drawing::Size(41, 18);
            this->label6->TabIndex = 14;
            this->label6->Text = L"Jahr";
            // 
            // label7
            // 
            this->label7->AutoSize = true;
            this->label7->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::Transparent;
            this->label7->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Microsoft Sans Serif", 11.25F, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Bold, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point, 
                static_cast<System::Byte>(0)));
            this->label7->ForeColor = System::Drawing::Color::Black;
            this->label7->Location = System::Drawing::Point(282, 43);
            this->label7->Name = L"label7";
            this->label7->Size = System::Drawing::Size(92, 18);
            this->label7->TabIndex = 15;
            this->label7->Text = L"Restschuld";
            // 
            // label8
            // 
            this->label8->AutoSize = true;
            this->label8->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::Transparent;
            this->label8->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Microsoft Sans Serif", 11.25F, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Bold, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point, 
                static_cast<System::Byte>(0)));
            this->label8->ForeColor = System::Drawing::Color::Black;
            this->label8->Location = System::Drawing::Point(282, 69);
            this->label8->Name = L"label8";
            this->label8->Size = System::Drawing::Size(58, 18);
            this->label8->TabIndex = 16;
            this->label8->Text = L"Zinsen";
            // 
            // label9
            // 
            this->label9->AutoSize = true;
            this->label9->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::Transparent;
            this->label9->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Microsoft Sans Serif", 11.25F, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Bold, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point, 
                static_cast<System::Byte>(0)));
            this->label9->ForeColor = System::Drawing::Color::Black;
            this->label9->Location = System::Drawing::Point(282, 94);
            this->label9->Name = L"label9";
            this->label9->Size = System::Drawing::Size(62, 18);
            this->label9->TabIndex = 17;
            this->label9->Text = L"Tilgung";
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
            this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
            this->BackgroundImage = (cli::safe_cast<System::Drawing::Image^  >(resources->GetObject(L"$this.BackgroundImage")));
            this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(500, 300);
            this->Controls->Add(this->label9);
            this->Controls->Add(this->label8);
            this->Controls->Add(this->label7);
            this->Controls->Add(this->label6);
            this->Controls->Add(this->textBox8);
            this->Controls->Add(this->textBox7);
            this->Controls->Add(this->textBox6);
            this->Controls->Add(this->textBox5);
            this->Controls->Add(this->button1);
            this->Controls->Add(this->label5);
            this->Controls->Add(this->label4);
            this->Controls->Add(this->label3);
            this->Controls->Add(this->label2);
            this->Controls->Add(this->label1);
            this->Controls->Add(this->textBox4);
            this->Controls->Add(this->textBox3);
            this->Controls->Add(this->textBox2);
            this->Controls->Add(this->textBox1);
            this->Name = L"Form1";
            this->Text = L"Hypotheken Rechner by Tobias Rohde";
            this->Load += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::Form1_Load);
            this->ResumeLayout(false);
            this->PerformLayout();

        }
#pragma endregion

    private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
        for(c=0;c<100;c++){
        Money=Money-Redemption;
        Mone[c]=Money;
        Interes[c]=Money*Percent/100;
        Redemption = tp-Zinse[c]; //tp to pay
        Redemptio[c]=Redemption;
    }
        for(c=0;c<100;c++){
            textBox5->Text = Year[c];
            textBox6->Text = Mone[c];
            textBox7->Text = Interes[c];
            textBox8->Text = Redemptio[c];
            if(Mone[c]<=0)
        {
            break;
        }
        }
             }
};
}
```

I am getting this Error :

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Hypotheken Rechner, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  Hypotheken Rechner.cpp
1>c:\users\tobi\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\hypotheken rechner\hypotheken rechner\Form1.h(17): error C4368: cannot define 'Year' as a member of managed 'HypothekenRechner::Form1': mixed types are not supported
1>c:\users\tobi\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\hypotheken rechner\hypotheken rechner\Form1.h(18): error C4368: cannot define 'Mone' as a member of managed 'HypothekenRechner::Form1': mixed types are not supported
1>c:\users\tobi\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\hypotheken rechner\hypotheken rechner\Form1.h(19): error C4368: cannot define 'Interes' as a member of managed 'HypothekenRechner::Form1': mixed types are not supported
1>c:\users\tobi\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\hypotheken rechner\hypotheken rechner\Form1.h(20): error C4368: cannot define 'Redemptio' as a member of managed 'HypothekenRechner::Form1': mixed types are not supported
1>c:\users\tobi\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\hypotheken rechner\hypotheken rechner\Form1.h(319): error C2039: 'Form1_Load' : is not a member of 'HypothekenRechner::Form1'
1>          c:\users\tobi\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\hypotheken rechner\hypotheken rechner\Form1.h(15) : see declaration of 'HypothekenRechner::Form1'
1>c:\users\tobi\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\hypotheken rechner\hypotheken rechner\Form1.h(319): error C2065: 'Form1_Load' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\users\tobi\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\hypotheken rechner\hypotheken rechner\Form1.h(319): error C3350: 'System::EventHandler' : a delegate constructor expects 2 argument(s)
1>c:\users\tobi\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\hypotheken rechner\hypotheken rechner\Form1.h(332): error C2065: 'Zinse' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\users\tobi\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\hypotheken rechner\hypotheken rechner\Form1.h(336): error C2664: 'void System::Windows::Forms::Control::Text::set(System::String ^)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'int' to 'System::String ^'
1>          No user-defined-conversion operator available, or
1>          No standard conversion exists from the boxed form of the arithmetic type to the target type
1>c:\users\tobi\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\hypotheken rechner\hypotheken rechner\Form1.h(337): error C2664: 'void System::Windows::Forms::Control::Text::set(System::String ^)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'int' to 'System::String ^'
1>          No user-defined-conversion operator available, or
1>          No standard conversion exists from the boxed form of the arithmetic type to the target type
1>c:\users\tobi\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\hypotheken rechner\hypotheken rechner\Form1.h(338): error C2664: 'void System::Windows::Forms::Control::Text::set(System::String ^)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'int' to 'System::String ^'
1>          No user-defined-conversion operator available, or
1>          No standard conversion exists from the boxed form of the arithmetic type to the target type
1>c:\users\tobi\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\hypotheken rechner\hypotheken rechner\Form1.h(339): error C2664: 'void System::Windows::Forms::Control::Text::set(System::String ^)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'int' to 'System::String ^'
1>          No user-defined-conversion operator available, or
1>          No standard conversion exists from the boxed form of the arithmetic type to the target type
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I tried a lot of stuff to fix this, i read alot about getting some declerations in the constructor and some stuff about managed and static things... Please help me fixing this!

Comment: It is a very unhealthy mix of C++/CLI and C code, the C++/CLI compiler will not put up with it.  You'll need to read at least an introductory book on C++/CLI programming to learn how to write this kind of code correctly.  Such as using the array<> keyword to declare managed arrays. Pay a visit to your local bookstore or library to get ahead.

Comment: ... du musst dringend nochmal von ganz vorne anfangen, ganz offensichtlich kennst du die Makros #include und das Schlüsselwort using nicht. Ehrlich gesagt : mit deinem Wissensstand sollte man nicht programmieren.

Comment: @specializt, klar kenne ich ich die ich lese gerade so ein buch namens Learning C++ in 24 Hours um die Basics zu verstehen. ich sagte ja ich bin noch nicht so gut!

Comment: @HansPassat i read a book called Learn C++ in 24 Hours for the basics! We are talking about hypothecary credits in school and we did it excel, and i thought/think it would be cool if I could make a program for calculating the credits. I learn the console application right now, and i just watched some tutorials about the windows forms application, so please help me, i want to learn! I WILL continue the console application book after this project, but I dont want to show a console to my teacher. hope you understand and thanks for the answer would be cool if you could edit my program so it works!

Comment: "24 Stunden" und "C++" sind 2 Dinge, die nicht im selben Satz genannt werden können. Das Buch kannste völlig getrost in den Mülleimer legen - wirste nix verpassen. Jeder, der ernsthaft behauptet (wenn auch nur über einen scherzhaften Buchtitel) dass man IRGENDeine Sprache in derartiger Zeit lernen kann ist ... geistig stark eingeschränkt.

Comment: Das finde ich jetzt nicht sehr Nett von dir. Als Anfänger sollte man doch wohl erst einmal ganz von vorne Anfangen?! War dein erstes Programm ein total komplexes Programm oder nur einen 10 Zeilen Console App die Hello World zeigt?... Also meins war eins dieser art und wenn da steht 24h meinen die damit so ein paar GRUNDLAGEN, das man in 24 stunden keine sprache lernen kann ist doch wohl klar, das steht nicht zur Diskussion!

Answer (score 0):

first issue is that when you defined your class with ref:

```
 public ref class Form1
```

you made your class managed. and string is not managed. so you are basically defining unmanged members in a managed class which is no allowed.

Comment: as the others mentioned this is not a very healthy code. but if you insist, you can try by using string^ to indicate that the string should be managed automatically, and use System::Array. but I suggest you to first read carefully about CLI/c++ before using this. btw, another issue you have is that you try to set an integer to the text, while there is no auto conversion.

Comment: yes i think you are right...! i thought console application code is the same like forms.. my fault! but could you fix it for me then ?

Comment: Use array<int>^ Year and initialize it in the ctor like this: Year= gcnew array< int >(100); then set string values in the textbox with textBox1->Text = System::Convert::ToString(Year[c]);